# Apache Httpd Rewrite without Context

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am not able to Rewrite the URL without a context, I want to suppress the context in the URI, Can you let me know, how to do that.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/home/$   
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/(.*)$ /flight-1.0.0/userLogin? [L,R]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^a=PRO$   
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/(.*)$ /proration-all-1.0.0/$2? [L,R]
```

On every rewrite following context will get viewed int the screen flight-1.0.0/proration-all-1.0.0/

*/flight-1.0.0*   
*/proration-all-1.0.0*

I want to hide the context, please suggest.
Thanks in advance.

Regards
Jawahar

Comment: What do you mean "suppress the context"? Do you want to avoid showing the modified URI to the viewer? In that case, @Jon Lin's fix (to remove "R") should do the job. As long as you don't have `http://domain_name`, it will default to a 200 code. If you add `http://domain_name` to the output URI, it will default to a 302 code and the viewer will see it.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `R` from the rewrite flags. The `R` flag tells mod_rewrite to redirect the browser, and this changes what's in the browser's location bar.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/home/$   
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/(.*)$ /flight-1.0.0/userLogin? [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^a=PRO$   
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/(.*)$ /proration-all-1.0.0/$2? [L]
```